# Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options unit_test_framework) (found version "1.75.0")

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to run Cell-DEVS-CO2_spread_indoor with `cmake ./` but I get this error: `Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options unit_test_framework) (found version "1.75.0")`.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Have a look into the code, is the exact Boost version required, i.e., 1.55.0 instead of >=1.55.0?

Comment: I do not think so. I updated Boost to 1.75.0 and it doesn't work either.